# Stability result for analytic continuations

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

Let $f(x):\mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ be a real function which extends meromorphically to the complex $\mathbf{C}$ plane to a function $\tilde f(z) : \mathbf{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{C}$. Let then $f_n(x): \mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$, with again meromorphic extensions $\tilde f_n(x): \mathbf{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{C}$, such that:

$f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x), x \in \mathbf{R}$

with some convergence criterion (for example uniformly or in some normed sense). Is it true that also:

$\tilde f_n(z) \rightarrow \tilde f(z), z \in \mathbf{C}$

for some convergence criterion???

For example can we say that the set of poles of $\tilde f_n$ will tend to the poles of $\tilde f$

I came across this question when trying to understand how analytical continuations can be practically performed. I did not find an answer yet.

Comment: Some sort of further constraints are surely needed: e.g., $f_n(z)=(z-2i)^{-n}$ converges uniformly to $f=0$ on $\mathbb R$, but have ever-deepening pole at $2i$...

Answer (score 1):

Define, for each $n\in\mathbb N$,$$\begin{array}{rccc}f_n\colon&\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{\pm\frac in\right\}&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\\&z&\mapsto&\displaystyle\frac{\sin\bigl(\sqrt nz\bigr)}{1+n^2z^2}.\end{array}$$Then the sequence $\bigl(f_n|_{\mathbb R}\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges (uniformly, I think, but I am not entirely sure) to the null function. However, there is no $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb R$ such that the sequence $\bigl(f_n(z)\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges.

Comment: Maybe I am just confused. The modulus |1+n^2z^2| diverges for n big, so that the modulus of f_n(z), for fixed z, tends to zero, and therefore f_n(z) as well ? Even if I am wrong, I thanks for the answer. I was hoping actually for some positive result also on just selected cases, for example when f_n(x) arise from an expansion into an orthogonal bases...

Comment: @Thomas You got the reason why $\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}f_n(z)=0$ when $z\neq0$. However, the argument fails when $z=0$. It that case, it is just a matter of noticing that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):f_n(0)=0$. Besides, if my answer was useful, perhapes that you could upvote it.

Comment: Dear Josè I do not understand yet. Sorry probably I am not getting it. You write in your answer "However, there is no z ∈ C∖R such that the sequence (fn(z)) n∈N converges", but in the last comment you say "lim n∈N fn(z)=0 when  z≠0". I do not see how these two sentences go together.

Comment: @Thomas I was talking about the case when $z\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Dear Josè, it seems to me that the modulus |1+n^2z^2| diverges for every z (complex) different from zero, and therefore the function you wrote converges to zero for big n in the whole complex plane, not only on the real axes.

Comment: @Thomes You are wrong. Yes, $|1+n^2z^2|$ goes to $+\infty$ if $z\neq0$. More precisely, it goes to $+\infty$ polynomially fast. But, if $z\notin\mathbb R$, then $|\sin z|$ gos to $+\infty$ *exponentially* fast.

Comment: sin(z) does not depend on n, so for fixed z is a costant. I thought you were referring to the criterion punctual convergence....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62931/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-thomas).

Comment: NB: MOST OF THE COMMENTS DO NOT APPLY ANY MORE SINCE THE AUTHOR MODIFIED HIS ANSWER IN ORDER TO SOLVE SOME OF THE ISSUES